# DNS of the server where ASP.NET application is run

Tags: asp.net

How to get to know DNS name of the server where ASP.NET application is run?

I want to get string "www.somehost.com" if my application URL is http://www.somehost.com/somepath/application.aspx

Is there some property of Server, Contex, Session or Request objects for this?

Thanks!

Comment: The Domain Name, or the Domain Name Server?

Comment: Are you trying to find the domain/host part of the URL used by the web user? Or the machine name of the server running the ASP.NET application? They're not necessarily the same.  Given you're considering the Request object, I suspect you're after the host part of the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the DNS IP for the server that is hosting the web site

```
void GetDNSServerAddress()
    {
        NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface ni in nics)
            {
                if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    IPAddressCollection ips = ni.GetIPProperties().DnsAddresses;

                    foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in ips)
                    {
                        Console.Write(ip.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

However, while writing this ive just seen your edited post, so i think this is what you are after is simply:

```
string host = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP_HOST server variable can give you what you need.

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
```

Comment: That[s the host from the http headers. If there's a reverse-proxy or something in front of the ASP.NET application server, it's probably not the name of the machine that's running the ASP.NET application

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the 'machine name' using

```
System.Environment.MachineName
```