# Path from where an ASP.NET application is run

Tags: asp.net, path

An ASP.NET application sends letters in HTML format with links to external images. These images are placed in the same folder where the application is deployed. So before sending it modifies a letter template in such way what the links are correct.

Now I use

```
new UriBuilder(Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, 
    Request.Url.Port, ResolveUrl("~")).ToString()
```

to get a path from where the application is run, but I want something more simple.

Some answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286791/dns-of-the-server-where-aspnet-application-is-run) were useful, but I still hope for better solution.

Thank you!

Comment: This does not look too complicated... Per application you would even need to do it only once and store the result. What do you want to make simpler?

Comment: I am looking for something like Application.StartupPath (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Request.ApplicationPath?